# HC-06 pairing to arduino

Tags: bluetooth, hc-06

I have a bluetooth module HC-06 and want to pair it to my Arduino UNO. The thing is when I researched how to do so, I got different answers. What pairing should I use? Thank you in advance. I have highlighted the differences.

First version:
https://www.instructables.com/id/Add-bluetooth-to-your-Arduino-project-ArduinoHC-06/

HC-06>>>Arduino

**VCC>>>>3.3v**

GND>>>>GND

TXD>>>>RXD

**RXD>>>>TXD**

Second version:
http://42bots.com/tutorials/hc-06-bluetooth-module-datasheet-and-configuration-with-arduino/

HC-06            <<>> Arduino

HC-06 Ground GND <<>> GND

**HC-06 VCC pin  <<>> 5v**

HC-06 TX/TXD pin <<>> Arduino RX

**HC-06 RX/RXD pin << resistors >> Arduino TX**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1):

Which you use depends on two factors: the HC-06 carrier board you have, and which Arduino you are using.

If your carrier board has (and most do) a 3.3V regulator then you power the board from 5V.

If your Arduino is a 5V Arduino (such as an Uno) then you need a voltage divider on the (arduino)TX->(hc)RX pins otherwise you risk damaging the bluetooth module.

Comment: Thanks. How can I tell the carrier board of the HC-06 only by looking at the device itself. I have no manuals or other information about it.

Comment: @B.Parvi Post a picture.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPIZS.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPEJb.jpg

Comment: @B.Parvi Ok, that's one of the normal cheap eBay carriers. Yes, it has a voltage regulator. Give it 5V on Vcc.